# send post request with javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

I am looking for a way to send post request for Oauth for using API.

I need to send this data by post method a specific URL.

> Authorization: Basic
>   `someId==`
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

When I try with jquery AJAX I have a CORS error.

Maybe with PHP is a better way but I do not know very well this language (init an ajax request to a PHP script to make my Oauth request and send back to the client the result)

I ask your help for helping me to choose the best solution I am an autodidact in programming so is not trivial for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it won't let you send a request to a different site from javascript. Sending it via PHP is usually the way to go. Unfortunately, it's not trivial to do. Maybe somebody else knows a better way, but I've always used the curl wrapper.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

So, you'd create an endpoint in PHP that does the offsite request you need. Your jQuery would then do a request to that endpoint.